# Canvas retains its old image upon mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I am using HTML `canvas` in my application.  To clear this canvas control I am using `clearRect(0, 0, width, height)`:

```
function ClearSignature(canvasid) { 
  var ctxt = document.getElementById(canvasid); 
  if (ctxt.getContext) { 
    var ctx = ctxt.getContext('2d'); 
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctxt.width, ctxt.height); 
  } 
}
```

Though the canvas gets cleared, it automatically retains the old picture when the mouse is moved over the control.  I am not sure how to overcome this.  Please help.

Comment: I meant to say "CANVAS Control"

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you included some code that reproduces the problem. I'm happy to help, but I don't really have the time to try to figure out how to cause the problem when you already have code that does it...

Comment: function ClearSignature(canvasid)
            {
                var ctxt = document.getElementById(canvasid);
                if (ctxt.getContext) {
                    var ctx = ctxt.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctxt.width, ctxt.height);
                }
            }

Comment: when I call this function, CANVAS gets cleared without any issue.  But when I move the mouse over the canvas control, it shows the old image automatically.

Comment: I am not sure what I did.  But this is not happening now.  Hence please ignore this.